# OpenGL pModel translation

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

When I load an .obj file in GMax it is positioned in the center of the space (0,0,0). 
How can I change this position? Is there any special function?

I don't want to use glTranslatef. Rather I would like the whole pModel to move (the pModel structure to change). I found the function glmScale. Is there anything similar for translating or rotating?

When I load the obj I do smth like this:

```
pModelScaun=glmReadOBJ(filename);   
glmUnitize(pModelScaun);
glmFacetNormals(pModelScaun);
glmVertexNormals(pModelScaun,90.0);
```

and then I use the triangle to determine the light position and the shadow frascum

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < pModelScaun->numtriangles; i++)
{
    //compute the light vector (between the center of the current 
    //triangle and the position of the light (converted to object space)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        fvIncidentLightDir[j] = (pModelScaun->vertices[3*pModelScaun->triangles[i].vindices[0]+j] +
                                pModelScaun->vertices[3*pModelScaun->triangles[i].vindices[1]+j] +
                                pModelScaun->vertices[3*pModelScaun->triangles[i].vindices[2]+j]) / 3.0 - lp[j];            
    }
```

Can you point me a way in which I could use the transformation matrices in this situation?

Comment: Well, if you want to translate, then use glTranlatef!

It seems that you are not very used to the openGL states, but if i got where you're wrong, you have to have all your models at 0,0,0, and just translate the state when you have to draw them, after this, go back to 0,0,0 with load identity or popmatrix

Comment: It's true that I am new with openGl. I have a complicated algorithm that deals with shadowVolumes and it uses the inernal Structure of the pModel. That's why I would like to change it.

Comment: well, post some code of how you're loading yours models, and how are you drawing them. it would help to answer ;)

Comment: What is this pModel you're referring to? A certain class (docs?) a pointer to it... If you have access to vertex info you can just add your translation to them if you truly want to change the model. But I can't see why you would, even when you say it's needed for shadow volumes.

Comment: Moving an object by manually offsetting all the model vertices and uploading it all again to the GPU is just about the worst way to translate geometry.  For your shadow volumes why you can't pass your pModel vertices through the object's transformation matrix? (Which is how your graphics card does everything)

Comment: I updated my request with some code. Please see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have are using the vertices in object-space, and have transformed the light into their object-space, you can multiply the `fvIncidentLightDir` by your object's transformation matrix to transform it back into world space.